# Angular : How to load components dynamically? (component is unknown while compiling application)

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an use case where,

1. In Angular application user can upload any angular component.
2. The uploaded angular component now available to use inside same application.

Angular application is not aware of components that being uploaded at compile time.
I do not want to stop, recompile and rerun the application.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Building a platform which can be extended by developing custom components. Developers can use this platform to build UI application. It's kind of wix.com or page builder from wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not possible. Maybe one day it'll be as easy to export a native Web Component with ng-cli as generating a component. Check out https://github.com/robwormald/angular-elements mr. Wormald has done some experimenting on Angular->Custom elements.